# Launch Tkinter with undecorated window

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Python 2 and Tkinter, how can I make the Tk window launch without the title bar above the window?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

redbutton = Button(frame, text="Red", fg="red")
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

greenbutton = Button(frame, text="Brown", fg="brown")
greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT )

bluebutton = Button(frame, text="Blue", fg="blue")
bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )

blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Black", fg="black")
blackbutton.pack( side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all decoration from a Tkinter window (`Tk` or `Toplevel`) by using [.overrideredirect()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method):

```
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

Comment: This looks like it completely removes all formatting on the root window. Is there a way to 'only' remove the title bar?

Comment: If you want to only remove the title bar, I think you want something more like [Using TCL extensions to set native window style in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3306189/369450).